# Clearing object from JS memory

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to figure out a way to trigger garbage collection on an object created in javascript. I have an object being made that passes functions as arguments for callbacks, and would like to know if there is a suitable method of "nullifying" the object I've made within one of these call back functions.

See example below.

```
var fruit = new gameObject( "fruit", 20, 20, 30, 30, function(x,y,width,height,meta){

  //Render the gfx.
  gfxFruitRender(x,y,width,height,meta);

}, "s", function(x,y,meta,object){

  //On click.
  gameSfxTap.play();
  clearInterval( object.Animationinterval );
  objectDelete( object.objectId );

  //How can I reference the var fruit here, sort of like this = null; (I know this wont work though)


}, {
  "type" : "lime",
  "points" : 1,
  "rotation" : 0
} );
```

Comment: Not entirely sure if it'll trigger garbage collection though have you tried `delete myObject;`?

Comment: `fruit = null;`? If the object isn't referenced by any variable, it will be garbage collected automatically at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fruit = null;` will nullify `fruit`.

If you want to remove the variable `fruit`, and it is defined in the global context, you can use `delete fruit;`.